# Perforce SSL connection doesn't work with domain name but fine with IP address

Tags: ssl, perforce

I set up my SSL Perforce server with the official script on my Linux cloud vps. It's been fine but since I switched to 2022.1 P4V, I can't connect to it anymore. It says:

> SSL connect to ssl:perforce.mydomain.xyz:16666 failed (An existing connection was forcibly
> closed by the remote host. ).
> Remove SSL protocol prefix from P4PORT or fix the TLS settings.

After a lot of digging... I found out that I can connect just fine if I replace the domain with the actual IP. And before that, when I was using 2021.1 P4V, I could connect using my domain name.

I tried generating SSL certificates with "CN=perforce.mydomain.xyz" (and a couple similar but different addresses like just mydomain.xyz) but it didn't work.

I think it's a thing in 2021.2 because another app I use just released a new version and updated their P4 plugin to 2021.2 P4API and it doesn't work with my domain name anymore...

Has anyone experienced this? Is it still possible to use ssl with domain name instead of IP with the latest clients?

Comment: Sounds like you've already answered the question.  I'd suggest filing a bug report with Perforce; they're not likely to see or respond to it on SO.

Comment: I guess I just don't think it's very likely that something as expensive as Perforce would just break one of its major features in a major update... Being a free tier user I suppose I would have better luck with SO than with them...

Comment: Regressions happen; if you look at the relnotes you'll see a bunch of "this broke in version N and it's now been patched".  If you don't want to report the bug, downgrade to the working version for now, and wait for someone else to report the bug and for a patch to come out.

Comment: I would say "you could try to find the regression in the client code and submit a patch yourself" but looks like they haven't updated the open source drop since 2018.2.  https://workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/perforce_software/p4